# TransactionTemplate with rollbackFor

Tags: java, spring

I had several `@Transactional` private methods in my service and since `@Transactional` is not recommended over private methods I fixed them using `org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate`. Refactoring simple `@Transactional` was easy but I have one transactional method with `rollbackFor` attribute like this:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = ProcessingAlertException.class)
private void processAlert(Alert alert) {
    // do something
}
```

I don't exactly know, how to refactor it. `org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus` doesn't seem to have any suitable method.

Comment: Create a separate `TransactionTemplate` construct it with a transaction manager and custom `TransactionDefinition`. The `RuleBasedTransactionAttribute` is the one you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already decided to use `TransactionTemplate`, you can just call [`TransactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionStatus.html#setRollbackOnly--) for the given exception type within your `TransactionCallback`:

```
transactionTemplate.execute(transactionStatus -> {
    try {
      ...
    } catch (ProcessingAlertException ex) {
      transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly();
    }
});
```